# Why PayPal IPN work on Simulator, but not working on sandbox?

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I made a copy of [this script](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples/tree/master/php) on my server. And when I test it on IPN simulator in the developer panel, and everything is fine - I get emails and the logs are saved. But when I try to test the same script via sandbox facilitator account, the script does not work. I added the URL of the IPN script in the settings and I'm testing as buyer account.
Tell me please, what else can check?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be addressed to Paypal support.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure you've configured the SELLER sandbox account you're using with the IPN URL that you are testing.

Also, make sure this is not getting overridden by the PayPal button or API integration you are testing with.  For example, the Notify URL parameter can be used to specify an IPN URL in payment requests, and this would override anything set at the account level.

If you have the URL set properly, and you don't have an override, it should hit that URL as expected.  You can check the IPN History of the sandbox seller account to verify whether or not IPNs are getting sent.